# Xcode5 bot cannot authenticate to git repo

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, xcode5, bots, osx-server

I've set up a Mavericks box with OS X Server and Xcode 5.01. My source code is on a git repo that I have to access via https with a username and password.

In Xcode (on the same machine), I've cloned the project, built it and run it to check that all is fine. Then I've created a bot, selected the current server and scheme, and hit "integrate now". It fails after 5 seconds. I get:

```
Cloning into 'https_code_saers_com_myproject'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://code.saers.com': Device not configured
```

I checked that Xcode5 could pull new commits, so it has the username and password, yet by bot does not. Also, the "Device not configured" confuses me.

Any suggestion to how I can explicitly set the Username and Password?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: I've opened a thread on the Apple Dev forums here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/211312?tstart=0 with reference to the full log file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvz0t3n2hf1yh72/XCode5BotsLog.txt

Comment: can you work around it by using rsa keys rather than a password.

Comment: Nope, I don't have that control over the git infrastructure, so I cannot add my key and use SSH, I'm stuck on HTTPS.

Comment: this just happened to me suddenly with Xcode 6 and OSX server 4.0.3. everything was working, and all of a sudden can't access any repos.  I can log in through a web browser with the same credentials no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may just be confusion in terminology, but the bot itself shouldn't be connecting to your repository.  OSX Server does that.  Before you can create a bot, you should've had to setup your repository in Server.  When you do that, you get the opportunity to set username and password for accessing the repository.

It sounds like perhaps you have XCode configured to synch with your repository, but you must separately set up Server to access it as well.  See the "XCode" tab in the Server app.

[image: Open "Server" and look for the XCode tab]
[image: Then setup your repository there]

Answer (score 0):

you may be running into the same problem we had- it was passphrase-protected keys. xcode + server + git cannot properly use passphrases on the keys.

thus, you must use a pashphrase-less key with os x server connecting to the git repo.

```
 ssh-keygen -p
```

hope it helps.

edit: you might need to enable HTTP access to the git repo with this command:

```
  git update-server-info # If planning to serve via HTTP
```

Comment: I'm sorry, like I mentioned I cannot use SSH, it's HTTPS using basic HTTP authentication

Comment: oh, you might need to enable HTTP access to the git repo with this command: git update-server-info# If planning to serve via HTTP